# Можно ли отменить добавление в бд через EFCore после выполнения SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

У меня есть большой метод в котором несколько добавлений в разные таблицы бд. Такое бывает, что на каком-то этапе вылетает исключение и поэтому полного результата работы программы нет (т.к отсутствуют записи в некоторых таблиц из-за исключения). Могу ли я после `SaveChanges` отменять сохранение?

Все методы добавления в следующем примере кода имеют структуру:

```
_context.MyConcreteModels.AddAsync(item);
_context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

```
public async Task BegMethod(Document item)
{
   await store1.AddItem(item); //В бд добавилось
   await store2.AddItem(new MyModel2 { ... }); //В бд добавилось

   //много разных и очень важных строк кода
   //..но вдруг исключение. И теперь те два добавления было бы неплохо "отменить".

   await store3.AddItem(new MyModel3 { ... }); 
}
```

Comment: если только всё делать в рамках одной транзакции

Comment: @Konst а как именно?

Comment: тут почитайте https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/saving/transactions